# Is there any way to initialize my tableViewCell with a model and use that inside the tableViewCell class to just populate the rest of properties?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, initialization, reuseidentifier

In the code below, I use a `didSet` to update the value of custom TableViewCell labels and image.

I initially tried changing the `init` method of the my `ArtistTableViewCell`. I tried changing it to:

```
init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?, artist: Artist) {
        self.artist = artist
...
}
```

But that didn't work because it seems that the line:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ArtistTableViewCell
```

wants to call a method with only this signature:

```
init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)
```

So my current code works. But it doesn't take `artist` as property to initialize with, is as below:

```
import UIKit

class ArtistTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var artist: Artist!{
        didSet{
            bioLabel.text = artist.bio
            nameLabel.text = artist.name
            artistImageView.image = artist.image
        }
    }

    lazy var bioLabel : UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.numberOfLines = 0

        return label
    }()

    lazy var nameLabel : UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.backgroundColor = .cyan
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return label
    }()

    lazy var artistImageView : UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return imageView
    }()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {

        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        contentView.addSubview(bioLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(nameLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(artistImageView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            bioLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor, constant: 8),
            bioLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            bioLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8),
            bioLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor)
            ])
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            artistImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor,constant: 8),
            artistImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            artistImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor, constant: -8),
            artistImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameLabel.topAnchor, constant: -8)
            ])

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            nameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8),
            nameLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:contentView.centerXAnchor, constant: -8),
            nameLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor)            
            ])
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

This is how I call it:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ArtistTableViewCell
    let artist = artists[indexPath.row]
    cell.artist = artist        

    return cell
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem? Except for the first bad `init` method, the rest of your code seems fine.

Comment: I just don't like doing `cell.artist = artist`, it shouldn't be that way because such a cell only makes sense if we do have an artist. so I was looking for a way to just do `cell = ArtistTableViewCell(artist: artist)`

Comment: But that's exactly how you should be doing it. Cell's get reused. You have to update each cell with the specific data it's being reused for.

Comment: Create a method that takes artist as an argument which in turn populated the other labels with data, instead of going the didSet route. And you can call this method like so cell.myMethod(artist)

Comment: Not exactly related, but I find this post related: http://www.thomashanning.com/the-most-common-mistake-in-using-uitableview/